# Solving $\int\limits_{0}^t v_{term}\cdot(1-e^{\frac{-g\cdot t}{v_{term}}}) dt$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I was interested in figuring out how far a skydiver fell in some amount of time. I decided to do a derivation myself using newton's laws (to check to see if my integration skills were up to snuff - I'm self taught)

[1] $f = ma$

Total force acting on the object is the weight $mg$ and an opposing air resistance force $kv$

[2] $mg-kv = ma$

Acceleration is a small change in velocity over time $\frac{dv}{dt}$

[3] $mg-kv = m\frac{dv}{dt}$

I know that you hit terminal velocity when you are no longer accelerating when falling so that means $\frac{dv}{dt} = 0$

[4] $mg-kv_{term} = 0$

[5] $v_{term} = \frac{mg}{k}$

back to the main equation [3] we can rearrange splitting up the $dv$ and $dt$ and pull out $m$

[6] $\int\limits_{0}^tdt = m\cdot\int\limits_{0}^v \frac{1}{mg-kv}  dv$

I know that usually you would use $u$ as a lower bound but I'm only looking at skydivers falling out of some plane I'm assuming has no vertical speed so instead I used 0.

Doing some u substitution

[7] $u = mg-kv$

[8] $\frac{du}{dv} = -k$

[9] $dv = -\frac{1}{k}\cdot du$

I read somewhere that you should rescale the bounds when you are using u substitution so using [7] and [9] I get

[10] $\int\limits_{0}^tdt = \frac{-m}{k}\cdot\int\limits_{mg}^{mg-kv} \frac{1}{u}  du$

[11] $t = \frac{-m}{k} \cdot ln(\frac{mg-kv}{mg})$

[12] $v=\frac{mg(1-e^{\frac{-kt}{m}})}{k}$

We can make it look nicer using [5] and we can clean up the exponential by modifying [5] so we don't have any $k$s in the equation

[13] $-\frac{g}{v_{term}} = -\frac{k}{m}$

Substituting [13] in the exponential and [5] into main equation of [12] we get

[14] $v=v_{term}(1-e^{\frac{-gt}{v_{term}}})$

I graphed this using geogebra and a hypothetical terminal velocity of 20 on earth and looking at the graph it looks like what I would expect, the velocity increases over time but starts to slow down as it approaches 20.

Velocity is a change in displacement over time $\frac{ds}{dt}$

[15] $\frac{ds}{dt}=v_{term}(1-e^{\frac{-gt}{v_{term}}})$

...And this is where I get stuck. I know I can split open the derivitives and move the dt across but trying to integrate this is confusing to me. I plugged this into wolfram alpha to see what the result might be and it's saying it should be:

[15] $s = v_{term}\cdot \frac{(v_{term}\cdot e^{\frac{-gt}{v_{term}}} + gt)}{g}$

note: I plugged in exactly "integrate w*(1-e^(-(g*t)/w)) dt" - I used $w$ in space of $v_{term}$

The problem is when I come up with some hypothetical examples for $g$ and $v_{term}$ and plug them into a graphing website such as geogebra when t is 0 it's showing that $s$ is $\frac{v_{term}^2}{g}$ which makes no sense. If the terminal velocity is 20m/s and you fall at 9.81 m/s^2 initially you have covered 0 distance, not 40.77m.

So that tells me that [15] must be wrong, so how on earth do you integrate $\int\limits_{0}^t v_{term}\cdot(1-e^{\frac{-g\cdot t}{v_{term}}}) dt$ ?

Thank you for listening and following my silly little math experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you integrated, you didn't account for the lower bound of the integral. Let me use $v'$ for the terminal speed and let me use $\alpha$ to denote $\frac{g}{v_t}$. You should also, strictly speaking, be integrating with respect to some dummy variable $t'$. So, we have that:
$$\int_{0}^{t} v'(1-\exp(-\alpha t')) \ dt' = \left[v't' +\frac{v}{\alpha} \exp(-\alpha t') \right]_{0}^{t} = v't +\frac{v}{\alpha} \exp(-\alpha t)-\frac{v}{\alpha}$$

This should make much more sense physically than what you got.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :)